# Save the custom created fee in checkout page and in the place order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

Here's my problem, I'm having a hard time adding the custom fee to the total price of the order page, I can add the custom fee on the checkout page but after I place the order, the total price is not accurate in the total price on checkout page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMTue.png)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). 
Then write your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @7uc1f3r Thats a very good question! John - did you?